# Redirect in flask does not actually redirect to the desired page.

Tags: python, redirect, flask

```
class XX(MethodView):
  def get(self):
           ....

  def post(self):
    error = None
        user = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

    print user,password
    if user == 'xxx' and password == 'xx':
        session['logged_in'] = True
        session['session_user'] = 'xx'                              
        return redirect("control")

    else:
        errors = []
        errors.append("Login error")
        return render_template("login.html" , errors=errors)

#adding rule for control Blueprint
control.add_url_rule("/control",view_func= ControlView.as_view('control'))
```

The code snippet checks for specific username,password and should redirect to a specific page.

When requested for the login page, a GET request is sent.The above snippet gets username and password and adds to session dictionary.The redirect method results in a POST request and response code is 302 FOUND followed by a GET request to desired page with 200 OK response code.

But the redirection does not happen, it remains on same login page.

what should redirect have as parameters?

```
redirect('control')

redirect(url_for('control'))

redirect(url_for('control.control'))
```

Why using `render_template('XX.html')` responds with 500 response code ??

Comment: You what to access GET method(XX-> get) ???

Comment: XX.html is a home page after login

Comment: try `redirect('/control')`

Comment: @kartheek :  No, it did not work.It gives 500 internal server error

Comment: no error beside 500 in console?

Comment: is it calling your get method??

Comment: @PaoloCasciello: No error besides 500,@kartheek: Yes it is calling the get method, response is the desired page content but it does not redirect to that page.

Answer (score 1):

Is this code inside of a blueprint named 'control'? *I'm guessing yes, based on the code shown above.*

When you're using blueprints, you cannot know the final URL (eg: `/control`) in advance, since the blueprint user can map the base URL anywhere they'd like.

The best way to redirect to your view, assuming this is a blueprint, is using the blueprint URL notation: `redirect(url_for('control.control'))`.

If this is NOT going to be used in a blueprint, you should be able to do something like: `redirect(url_for('control'))` so long as that's your view name when added to the route.

Hope this was clear.

If you're still having errors when trying to two above examples, enable Flask debugging (`app.config['DEBUG'] = True`) and re-try. The traceback should explain what's happening in more depth.

Comment: `redirect(url_for('control'))` worked with NO `Blueprint`, but with `Blueprint` `redirect(url_for('control.control'))` did not.

Comment: You might want to check your core application where you import your blueprint -- you'll want to ensure that your blueprint is actually named 'control' -- I suspect that's the issue.